# Forwarding GUI applications to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, gui, xorg, macos

I am attempting to write a GUI application for the Raspberry Pi using Python and Kivy. I want to do all the development on my Mac because it is far easier for me but then display the application on the RPi so I can make use of the touchscreen input I have setup.

I have seen many posts on X11 forwarding whereby I can run an RPi GUI application on my Mac but I want to go in reverse and run the application on my Mac but forward the monitor output to the RPi. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run it on Mac and use only touchscreen from the Raspberry Pi you can start SSH daemon with X11 forward support on Mac and connect through the Raspberry Pi using SSH and run your app.

You can read more about configuring here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23033038/5604507

Comment: Good answer. I do that on my windows PC using CygwinX by using the default LXDE with no additional setup.